# stop user interaction after CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgrect

I am trying to set up a little part of a game where the User drags a Label on to another one. If he did so, the Label resets and the players Points increment.

The Problem is that if I keep the Label pressed, I get an infinite amount of points because the Rect I created does not reset it's position as long as I keep my finger on the screen.

Here's the Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panrecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePangesture:)];

    [self.dragMe addGestureRecognizer:panrecognizer];
}

- (void)handlePangesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    self.dragMe.center = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.dragMe.superview];

    CGRect dragMerect = self.dragMe.frame;

    CGRect endZonerect = self.endZone.frame;

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(dragMerect, endZonerect)) {

        dragMerect.origin.x = 100;
        dragMerect.origin.y = 100;
        self.dragMe.center = dragMerect.origin;

        Points++;

        self.points.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Points: %d",Points];

        NSLog(@"Rect is Intersecting");

        NSLog(@"%d",Points);
    }
}
```

Hopefully You guys know what I'm talking about and how to fix it!

Thanks in advance, Niklas

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer has status property like gesture begin, end, move, ... Use this status property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to disable all userInteraction then use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Don't forget to enable it after resetting the label:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```